# Javadoc not auto-generating in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

I'm having trouble with the file templates for Java Development in IntelliJ IDEA. I created an includes file to be parsed out  and create Javadoc Comments from it.

File > Settings > Editor > File and Code Templates > Includes Tab

I added these variables to my File Header:

```
@name ${NAME}
@author #set( $Company = "Avaruus Studios" )
@date ${DATE}
```

[image: File and Code Templates - Includes Tab]

I then added the parse directive to the File Template:

```
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end
#parse("File Header.java")
public class ${NAME} {
}
```

[image: File and Code Templates - Files Tab]

When I add a new Java Class, the Javadoc Header Comments that are generated show up as errors:

[image: New Java Class Error]

How can I fix this template so that they are generated correctly?

Comment: Be aware that `@name` and `@date` are not standard javadoc tags, so they won’t show up if the javadoc is generated by someone who isn’t using IntelliJ, unless that someone provides `-tag` or `-taglet` options to javadoc.  See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/javadoc/doc-comment-spec.html for the entire list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javadoc needs to be inside comment brackets for java, so try changing your template file to:

Edit:

```
#set( $Company = "Avaruus Studios" )
/**
* @name ${NAME}
* @author ${Company}
* @date ${DATE}
*/
```

Comment: I changed the includes file to the above.

I get the following:

`package main;
/**
 * @author * @date 1/16/2020
 * @name tree
 */
public class tree {
}`
It does not format it correctly or add in the custom variable I set.

Comment: What should the @author tag say? The name of the company or the user name?

Comment: Why is that when I paste it in exactly as the comment is, the Javadoc is not generated in the same order?

Comment: Thats really strange, for me it is generating it with the same order as above.
The #set() is a function to set a variable, the variable name is $Company and you are assigning it the Avaruus Studios value
Inside the comments you just need to refer back to that variable and use it.
If you dont want to deal with the variable, just put the name on the @author tag and it should be done.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure. Mine show up with the `@author` tag first, then the `@name` and `@date`. But at least they don't show up as an error.